# Two spring kafka consumer with different configuration in one application

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am newbie to Kafka. I am working on a Spring-Kafka POC. Our KAFKA severs are Kerberized. With all required configuration, we are able to access the Kerberized Kafka server. Now we have another requirement where we have to consume topics from non-Kerberized (Simple Kafka Consumer) Kafka servers. Can we do this in single application by creating another KafkaConsumer with its own Listener?

Comment: Copious grammar edits.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; just define a different consumer factory bean for the second consumer.

If you are using Spring Boot's auto configuration, you will have to manually declare both because the auto configuration is disabled if a user-defined bean is discovered.